# if not checked input then follow

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

I tried to google, but couldn't find anything about this situation, mb I googled bad :) whatever, all i need is to create a form with one input checkbox, when the checkbox is checked it goes to a link, when it is not checked, it follow another link, for now im stuck right here:

```
<form name="eol" method="post" 
                 action="/index.cfm?fuseaction=objects2.view_product_list&eol=1">

Show EOL Products<input type="checkbox" name="eol_input" value="0" <cfif not isdefined('attributes.eol')><cfelse>checked</cfif> onClick="eol.submit();">
</form>
```

how do i make it follow the other link when the checkbox is NOT checked?! i think it can be done by javascript(jquery), so does anyone have any idea?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("[name='eol_input']").click(function(){
    if(this.checked){
        //is checked
        window.location = "http://link1.com/";
    } else {
        //not checked
        window.location = "http://link2.com/";
    }
});
```

Comment: @abrabr: For the love of all that is sane, please don't use `.is(":checked")` to test the state of a single checkbox element.  `this.checked` will get you the same result in all browsers, and is much better for performance. For more information, take a look at http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/10/utilizing-the-awesome-power-of-jquery-to-access-properties-of-an-element.

Comment: Wow, that is some speed difference...nice article to, +1. OK, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 2):

Is this the kind of thing you're after?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form[name="eol"]').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        var urls = {
            "checked" : "http://foo.com/",
            "unchecked": "http://bar.com/"
        };

        var isChecked = $('input[name="eol_input"]:checked').length;
        window.location = isChecked ? urls['checked'] : urls['unchecked'];
    });
});
```